# How can I get informations about my string using JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Hello I have this string using Python :

```
a = '{"test0": [{"test1": [{"test2": 0, "test3": "a", "test4": "test5", 
"test6": "b", "test7": {"test8": [{"test9": "", "test10": [""]}], 
"test11": [{"test12": "", "test12": []}], "test13": [{"test14": "", 
"test15": []}]}, "test16": 0, "test17": 0}], "test18": "", "test19": "", 
"test20": 0, "test21": 0}], "test22": ""}'
```

But when I try this `a["test0"]` it does not work... Do you have any ideas to make workable this ?

Thank you !

Comment: `a` is a dictionary from the looks of how you posted it, so `a['"test[0]"]` should work. else use `json.loads(a)` to convert it into one

Comment: What are you expecting to see as the output of `a["test0"]`?

I get `[{'test1': [{'test2': 0, 'test3': 'a', 'test4': 'test5', 'test6': 'b', 'test7': {'test8': [{'test9': '', 'test10': ['']}], 'test11': [{'test12': []}], 'test13': [{'test14': '', 'test15': []}]}, 'test16': 0, 'test17': 0}], 'test18': '', 'test19': '', 'test20': 0, 'test21': 0}]` which is what I would expect to see from your code.

Comment: That's not a string, but a dictionary. And it works for me.You should better explain the "*it does not work*" part.

Comment: Unfortunately `'it does not work'` is not a question on stack overflow.

Comment: when I try this `a['test[0]"']` I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Better keep expected Output and errors you got next time, I think its a string,Try to a = eval(a) or read about 'ast'

Comment: Your original code as posted works for me. And I can see from actually running the code that you have a duplicate key `'test12'` in there.

Comment: Put effort into asking your question. Its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What I thought was to use `json.load()` or `json.dumps()` but without success ...

Comment: Please, we cannot help you unless you explain what you want out of your code.

Comment: I just want to read my string a like a JSON for instance I want to be able to do this `a['test0']`

Comment: Now that you have edited your question your code has a syntax error. I can't run it anymore.

Comment: Yes because a was a string and not a dictionnary that is my problem ... :/

Comment: Write first and last `"` as `'` - otherwise it's not a correct python string (all `"` pairs would be matched, not first and last) and remove line breaks (why did you break the string? I have to edit it while copying, that's annoying). Then `json.loads(a)` will work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your actual code is, but if I were to guess I would write this:

```
a = '{"test0": [{"test1": [{"test2": 0, "test3": "a", "test4": "test5", "test6": "b", "test7": {"test8": [{"test9": "", "test10": [""]}], "test11": [{"test12": "", "test12": []}], "test13": [{"test14": "", "test15": []}]}, "test16": 0, "test17": 0}], "test18": "", "test19": "", "test20": 0, "test21": 0}], "test22": ""}'

d = json.loads(a)

print(d['test0'])
```

Output:

```
[{'test1': [{'test2': 0, 'test3': 'a', 'test4': 'test5', 'test6': 'b', 'test7': {'test8': [{'test9': '', 'test10': ['']}], 'test11': [{'test12': []}], 'test13': [{'test14': '', 'test15': []}]}, 'test16': 0, 'test17': 0}], 'test18': '', 'test19': '', 'test20': 0, 'test21': 0}]
```